# Rendering d3pie charts with angular2 beta 15

Tags: angular, d3pie.js

I am looking for a way to render d3pie charts with angular2 beta 15. If anyone could point me to a good example, it'd be of great help!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap d3 processing into an Angular2 component as described below:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app'
  template: `
    <svg>
    </svg>
  `
})
export class App {
  constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    var width = 960,
      height = 500,
      radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

    var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
      .outerRadius(radius - 10)
      .innerRadius(0);

    var labelArc = d3.svg.arc()
      .outerRadius(radius - 40)
      .innerRadius(radius - 40);

    var pie = d3.layout.pie()
      .sort(null)
      .value(function(d) { return d.population; });

    var svg = d3.select(this.elementRef.nativeElement).select('svg')
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

    d3.csv("data.csv", type, function(error, data) {
    if (error) throw error;

    var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
      .data(pie(data))
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc");

    g.append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.age); });

    g.append("text")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + labelArc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.age; });
    });

    function type(d) {
      d.population = +d.population;
      return d;
    }
  }
}
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/rXvxpa7uguN00yzvwc72?p=preview based on the sample https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887235.

Answer (score -1):

There are many great libraries for charting. They work well with everything, not just angular. Try either of these

[fusion charts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/angularjs-charts/#/demos/ex1)

[Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/3d-pie)

Comment: OP explicitly asked about d3. You have suggested that the tail wag the dog into a cat.

Comment: I'm familiar with fusioncharts but as far as I know they do not have a plugin for angular 2 . I am looking for a working example with angular2 beta 15 .

Comment: @drewmoore...Given the never ending terrible grammar on SO and since I have never heard of that library, I assumed he was simply asking about 3D pie charts. Both links will help him with that in angular. The down vote was not necessary.